# MonoTouch throws SIGSEGV when right detail disclosure button on annotation is clicked

Tags: ios, event-handling, xamarin.ios, uibutton

## The Code:

```
UIButton rightButton = UIButton.FromType (UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure);

rightButton.TouchUpInside += (o, e) => { Console.WriteLine("hello"); };
```

## Stacktrace:

...

## Native stacktrace:

```
0   taggr                               0x000908fc mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 284
1   taggr                               0x00005c98 mono_sigsegv_signal_handler + 248
2   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x95c2859b _sigtramp + 43
3   ???                                 0xffffffff 0x0 + 4294967295
4   UIKit                               0x0219355a -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
5   UIKit                               0x02238b76 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
6   UIKit                               0x0223903f -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 503
7   UIKit                               0x022382fe -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 549
8   UIKit                               0x021b8a30 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 513
9   UIKit                               0x021b8c56 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 273
10  UIKit                               0x0219f384 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 464
11  UIKit                               0x02192aa9 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 8196
12  GraphicsServices                    0x0478afa9 PurpleEventCallback + 1274
13  CoreFoundation                      0x011951c5 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
14  CoreFoundation                      0x010fa022 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 146
15  CoreFoundation                      0x010f890a __CFRunLoopRun + 2218
16  CoreFoundation                      0x010f7db4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 212
17  CoreFoundation                      0x010f7ccb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
18  GraphicsServices                    0x04789879 GSEventRunModal + 207
19  GraphicsServices                    0x0478993e GSEventRun + 114
20  UIKit                               0x02190a9b UIApplicationMain + 1175
21  ???                                 0x09ff8784 0x0 + 167741316
22  ???                                 0x09ff79d0 0x0 + 167737808
23  ???                                 0x09ff7878 0x0 + 167737464
24  ???                                 0x09ff7907 0x0 + 167737607
25  taggr                               0x0000a002 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 722
26  taggr                               0x00169efe mono_runtime_invoke + 126
27  taggr                               0x0016dfe4 mono_runtime_exec_main + 420
28  taggr                               0x00173405 mono_runtime_run_main + 725
29  taggr                               0x00067205 mono_jit_exec + 149
30  taggr                               0x002116d5 main + 2837
31  taggr                               0x00003055 start + 53
```

Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That code is both right and wrong depending on it's context. Let's assume it's wrong (with the stack trace) because it's used like:

```
void BadCase ()
{
    UIButton rightButton = UIButton.FromType (UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure);
    rightButton.TouchUpInside += (o, e) => { Console.WriteLine("hello"); };
}
```

In this case `rightButton` can be collected (by the garbage collector) once the method returns (since there's no managed reference to the local variable). However the **native** button can still exists and will try to call back (into **managed** code) when a touch event occurs. This will lead to a crash (since the **managed** instance was collected).

```
UIButton rightButton;

void GoodCase ()
{
    rightButton = UIButton.FromType (UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure);
    rightButton.TouchUpInside += (o, e) => { Console.WriteLine("hello"); };
}
```

You can easily avoid this by keeping a reference to the button, e.g. by promoting it from a local variable to a field. That will prevent the GC to collect the **managed** button until the instance (of the type) is disposed. This means the **native** button will be able to call back into **managed** land and output your `hello`.

Comment: You're welcome :-) OTOH the right way to thank people on stackoverflow is to upvote (orange up arrow) their answers (or questions) and **if** it solves your problem/question then mark (grey/green checkmark below the votes) the question as answered (so other people doing search can find it too).

Comment: You got it Poupou! Your reply solved my issues. Marking as resolved.

Comment: Thanks, very very much!! This help me a lot, I've been stuck on this for a while.